# Sequelize, find where sum of two fields (one is date and another is number of hours) is bigger then Now

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a table:

```
createdOn: DateTime,
alarmDeadline: SmallInt
```

I need to find all records where (`createdOn` + `alarmDeadline` > `new Date()`)
in other words: `find all records where date created from adding date and hours are bigger then Now`).

I need to do it using `Sequelize` for `MySQL`.
Any help please? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Sequelize.literal`:

```js
const foudnRecrods = await Model.findAll({
  where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('DATE_ADD(createdOn,INTERVAL alarmDeadline HOUR'), '>', new Date())
});
```